# Make the app execute a function in the background

Tags: ios, swift, background, notifications

I'd like my app to execute a function on a regular time interval while my phone is locked so notifications can be displayed when needed.

I understood I should use `UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval` for the time interval so I set that in the `AppDelegate`'s`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function. The `Background Mode` is also set in my `info.plist`.

I put my `refreshData` function in `AppDelegate`'s `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` and when I use the `Simulate Background Fetch` debug control with the app loaded on my phone everything works beautifully, but nothing happens by itself when I put the phone aside.

I guess `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` is never called by itself on the time interval I set. How can I be sure it is running every 60 seconds as planned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  iOS decides when and how often to call your app in the background, not you.  You can simply ask for time and hope for the best.  If the user uses your app a lot, then the OS will give you more background time.

If you want more than that, you can send an APNS from an external server to the device, and that will wake up the app and give you some processing time.

[This article](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) describes your options in detail.

Comment: Thank you very much David. Does it mean my method is good anyway? Do you know how an app like Tinder can send notifications for new messages and matches in that case? Isn't the app working in the background and then displaying new events?

Comment: They are using a remote APNS notification.  The Tinder server is sending an APNS down to the device, which causes the notification.  The app does not even need to be running to show an APNS.

Comment: Hi David! If I read the documentation correctly, what I need is to send a push notification to the device to initiate a download and then display the notification depending on what the downloaded and analyzed data returned is this correct? Is it possible to set a server to send this kind of notifications on a regular basis?

Comment: Yes @Martin33000 the server can send notifications as quickly as it wants to.  Only the last received notification will be processed but if your goal is just to get background time, you can send them on a regular interval.